# dynamically add a method to the app delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

Say I have this instance method [1]:

```
    -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
               openURL:(NSURL *)url {

      NSLog(@"url --> %@", url); 
      //Do something...
      return YES;
    }
```

And if I am not mistaken, `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` [2]
is the instance of my app delegate.

I want to dynamically add my instance method [1] to the app delegate [2] from any other class.

I have found that `class_addMethod` [*info](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_addMethod) might help me, but it mentions nothing about how to specify if its an instance method or a class method.

**Edit:**

Following  @mipadi 's advice bellow, I am trying to call

`class_addMethod([AppDelegate class], @selector(newMethod), (IMP)myMethodIMP, "v@:");`

but I get the following errors:

- `Missing '[' at start of message send expression`
- `Expected ']'`
- `Size of array has non-integer type 'Class'`

And the following warning:

- `Type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'`

I am really not sure what is wrong and this errors make little sense to me.

Comment: Why? Explain what you are really trying to accomplish. There is likely a much better solution to your problem.

Comment: Yep, sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/192165).

Comment: I can't think of a use case for this. can you explain why you want to do that?

Comment: I am creating a module for react native, so I don't want to modify my AppDelegate.m file. But this code only works if it is added directly in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class_addMethod` always adds an *instance method* to a class. To add a *class method*, you would add the method to your class's *meta-class*.

Let's say your delegate class is called `MyDelegate`. Obviously you can create instances of `MyDelegate`. For example, in `id obj = [[MyDelegate alloc] init]`, `obj` is an instance of `MyDelegate`. However, the `MyDelegate` class itself is an instance of its *meta-class*. It is this meta-class to which you add `MyDelegate`'s class methods, because `MyDelegate`'s class methods are actually instance methods defined on its meta-class.

So, to add an instance method, you'd do something like this:

```
class_addMethod([MyDelegate class], @selector(newMethod), (IMP) newMethodImpl, newMethodTypeSig);
```

To add a class method, you'd do the same with `MyDelegate`'s meta-class as the first argument, which you can get using `object_getClass`:

```
class_addMethod(object_getClass([MyDelegate class]), @selector(newClassMethod), (IMP) newClassMethodImpl, newClassMethodTypeSig);
```

---

(Note that somewhat confusingly, `[myDelegateInstance class]` and `[MyDelegate class]` actually return identical objects; that is, `+[MyDelegate class]` returns itself. `[MyDelegate class]` does *not* return `MyDelegate`'s meta-class, as you may expect.)